# divide in summation in CPLEX

Tags: cplex, opl

I want to divide two dvar cplex  in IBM cplex :

```
dvar int BP_i_j [r_i][r_j]; 

dvar int Q_i_j_t [r_i][r_j][r_t];

 dexpr float cost = p_n * sum(t in r_t , j in r_j) ( 

      sum(i in r_i )  c_i_j_t [i][j][t] *  x_i_j_t [i][j][t]  + 

      sum(i in r_i )  BP_i_j[i][j] * x_i_j_t [i][j][t]  /   Q_i_j_t [i][j][t] 

)
```

and I get

> Function operator/(dvar float+,dvar float+) not available in context CPLEX

haw to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi you could use cpo : write « using CP; »

Comment: Story, I dont understand what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

```
using CP;
dvar int x;
dvar int y in 1..10;

dexpr float z=x/y;

subject to
{
z==0.5;
}

execute
{
writeln(x,"/",y);
}
```

works